# What is the '1995-12-17T03:24:00' for of a datetime called?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, datetime

I'm trying to to create a method that returns a random date in that format in the from today to a year ago. So right now I have

```
var curDate = new Date(),
    oneYearAgo = curDate-365*24*60*60*1000, 
    randDate = new Date(Math.random() * (CurDate - OneYearAgo) + OneYearAgo);
```

But now how do I convert that to a string like in the title? I'm looking through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and can't figure it out because I don't know what the name of that format is.

Comment: `randDate.toISOString()`

Comment: Also, 365 days doesn't always equal a year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the format is [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).